# ipython - get list of all kernels (user + default)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am looking for a way to get a list (or dict) with the names of all installed ipython kernels in the systems programmatically (not via command line). So far I have this:

```
from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecManager
print(KernelSpecManager().find_kernel_specs())
```

or (but it gives a deprecation warning):

```
from IPython.kernel.kernelspec import find_kernel_specs
print(find_kernel_specs())
```

There is also a way using ipykernel, but haven't found any docs.

All of the above give me a dictionary with the kernels I have installed using `ipykernel`, but not the default kernel (e.g. `Python 3`) which shows in the notebook:

```
{'lab2': '/home/alex/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/lab2',
 'lab3': '/home/alex/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/lab3',
 'python2': '/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2'}
```

Is there a way to get the list of ALL kernels?

Answer (score 1):

When I follow a slightly different procedure than what you have above, I see a python3 kernel.  I'm doing the following with Jupyter 4.4.0 installed.

```py
import jupyter_client
M = jupyter_client.kernelspec.KernelSpecManager()
M.find_kernel_specs()
```

It outputs a dict, with content like the following.

```
{'javascript': '/Users/someone/Library/Jupyter/kernels/javascript', 'python3': '/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3'}
```

[Here's a link to the relevant docs.](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/kernelspec.html#jupyter_client.kernelspec.KernelSpecManager)